# Constructor of class before main() (C++)

Tags: c++

I have a Singleton class:

```
// in global space
TNCManager *TNCManager::_globalInstance = new TNCManager();
```

Why is the constructor of `TNCManager` executed before the `main()` function?

Comment: Short answer: because this is behavior specified in the standard. Long answer: get rid of it.

Comment: Since it's global, it has to be fully constructed before `main` begins. If it wasn't how could you use it? If it happened sometime during `main` (maybe handled by a different thread), how would you know if it was constructed or not? If it happened after `main`, the program would be over.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern for the idiomatic way and lazy construction.

Comment: When did you expect it to be performed?

Comment: @Kevin: That's not _quite_ true. It's required to be fully constructed before any code in that code unit (cpp file) gets executed. The assumption that it's before main is a common cause of bugs :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does constructor of TNCManager perform before `main()` function?

All of the global statically allocated objects will be instantiated before `main()` executes.
Hence the constructor is called with `new TNCManager()`.

The idiomatic way, that avoids the construction before any access (lazy instantiation) is to write:

```
// in class space
class TNCManager {
public:
    TNCManager& instance() {
        static TNCManager theInstance;
        return theInstance;
    }
    // ...
};
```

See more details explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern).

Comment: The downside is that every use of `instance` gets a branch and a atomic flag check. While branch has a chance of being predicted (not necessarily!) atomic flag penalty is unavoidable.

Comment: @Raindrop7, no, you can't define global objects in `main`.

Comment: @SergeyA That atomic flag check sounds bearable for most situations.

Comment: @Raindrop7 _"why? I'd like to know"_ Because they're local to `main()` and not _global_.

Comment: @Raindrop7 I don't get your concern?

Answer (score -1):

Practically, because main () might, and should be able to, use TCNManager. The way applications work is to allocate memory, load the code and data, initialize storage and then call _main (). Before C++, initializing the data simply involved copying the initial data to the storage location. With classes, this involves calling the constructor.